# MSBuild, build dependent projects with different configurations

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I've a (C++) solution with a project, Tools, and another project, Main. Main depends on Tools.

I can build this project easily using MSBuild, with for example,

```
msbuild /t:configuration="Release" Main.sln
```

The Tools project only have the "Release" and "Debug" configuration. The Main project also have a "Release Lite" configuration - from within Visual Studio I can use the Configuration Manager to have it build Tools using "Release" config and Main using "Release Lite" configuration.

How can I tell MSBuild to build Tools using one configuration, and Main using another configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In Visual Studio, go to menu `Build > Configuration Manager`.
2. In the Configuration Manager, create a new solution configuration by opening *Active Solution Configurations* dropdownlist and selecting `New...`. (make sure you untick the *Create new project configurations* checkbox)
3. In this new solution configuration, select the configuration that you want to use for each project.
4. Run msbuild `msbuild /t:configuration="YourNewConfig" Main.`

Comment: @Anonym The /t:configuration switch is applied at solution level. You could also edit the solution "Release" configuration to use "Release Lite" configuration on the Main project. Follow step 1 above, but in step 2 choose the "Edit..." option